# Адаптивное позиционирование div на разных горизонтальных осях относительно картинки

Tags: html, scss, позиционирование

Приветствую.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно настроить позиционирование элементов .team__item относительно линии на картинки, чтобы при ресайзе окна они подстраивались, понятно, что media queries, но неохота писать почти на каждые 200 пикселей новые отступы, возможно есть какой-то более удобный способ?

Заранее спасибо.

Ссылка на код
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWjOVJ

```css
$primary-color: #e74c3c;
$secondary-color: #f4f5f9;

$text-primary-color: #999999;
$text-secondary-color: #ffffff;
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;

  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3ZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;

  src: local('Open Sans SemiBold'), local('OpenSans-SemiBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNShampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: bold;

  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzBampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}


.section {
  padding: 150px 0;
  &_background {
    &_image {
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  }
  &_no_padding {
    padding: 0;
  }
}



.heading {
  font-family: Opensans;
  &__title {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 3.6px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
  }
  &__subtitle {
    font-size: .875rem;/* Приближение из-за подстановки шрифтов */
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  &__notch {
    &:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      width: 6px;
      height: 36px;
      background-color: $primary-color;
    }
    &_left {
      &:before {
        margin-left: -30px;
        margin-top: 4px;
      }
    }
    &__right {
      &:after {
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-top: 4px;
      }
    }
  }
  &_center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  &_color {
    &_light {
      color: $secondary-color;
    }
    &_grey {
      color:  $text-primary-color;
    }
    &__dark {
      color: #6a6a6a;
    }
  }
}


.team {
  $b: &;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/WcVZqQx.png');
  height: 745px;
  &:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 745px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  }
  &__spec {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
    left: -12px;
    width: 150px;
  }
  &__name {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    color:  #e74c3c;
    font-size: 24px;/* Приближение из-за подстановки шрифтов */
    font-weight: 500;
    left: -15px;
    width: 150px;
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  }
  &__heading {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
  &__graph {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;
    height: 640px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://grimesco.de/teamgraph.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  &__item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 57px;
    height: 57px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid $primary-color;

    &:not(.team__item_active) {
      &:hover{
        width: 88px;
        height: 88px;
        box-shadow: -0px 10px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        &::after {
          position: absolute;
          content: '';
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-color:  rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.5);
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
        &::before {
          position: absolute;
          content: '';
          width: 1px;
          height: 50px;
          background-color: #ccc8c8;
          left: calc(50% + 1px);
          top: 85px;
        }
        #{$b}__name {
          display: block;
        }
        #{$b}__spec {
          display: block;
        }
      }
    }
    &_active {
      position: absolute;
      width: 88px;
      height: 88px;
      margin-top: -20px;
      box-shadow: -0px 10px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: 222;
      border: 3px solid $primary-color;
      &::before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        left: calc(50% + 1px);
        top: 85px;
        content: '';
        width: 1px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #ccc8c8;
        z-index: -333;
      }
    }
    &_1 {
      background-image: url(https://grimesco.de/team_1.jpg);
      top: 340px;
      left: 20%;
      &:not(.team__item_active) {
        &:hover {
          top: 320px;
        }
      }
      &:not(.team__item) {
        &::after {
          position: absolute;
          content: '';
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-color:  rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.5);
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
      }
    }
    &_2 {
      background-image: url(https://grimesco.de/team_1.jpg);
      top: 285px;
      left: 40%;
      &:not(.team__item_active) {
        &:hover {
          top: 265px;
        }
      }
      &:not(.team__item) {
        &::after {
          position: absolute;
          content: '';
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-color:  rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.5);
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
      }
    }
    &_3 {
      background-image: url(https://grimesco.de/team_1.jpg);
      top: 325px;
      left: 60%;
      &:not(.team__item_active) {
        &:hover {
          top: 305px;
        }
      }
      &:not(.team__item) {
        &::after {
          position: absolute;
          content: '';
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-color:  rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.5);
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
      }
    }
    &_4 {
      background-image: url(https://grimesco.de/team_1.jpg);
      top: 265px;
      left: 80%;
      &:not(.team__item_active) {
        &:hover {
          top: 245px;
        }
      }
      &:not(.team__item) {
        &::after {
          position: absolute;
          content: '';
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-color:  rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.5);
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="section section_background_color-2 section_no_padding team">
    <div class="heading heading_center team__heading">
      <h4 class="heading__title heading_color_light">Case study</h4>

      <p class="heading__subtitle heading_color_grey">
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap scrambled it to make a type.
      </p>

      <div class="separator separator_color_white"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="team__graph">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="team__item_1 team__item">
            <span class="team__name">123123</span>
            <span class="team__spec">123123</span>
          </div>

          <div class="team__item team__item_2">
            <span class="team__name">123123</span>
            <span class="team__spec">123123</span>
          </div>

          <div class="team__item team__item_3">
            <span class="team__name">123123</span>
            <span class="team__spec">123123</span>
          </div>

          <div class="team__item team__item_4">
            <span class="team__name">123123</span>
            <span class="team__spec">123123</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вижу 4 варианта решения.

**1. Resize линии**

Сделать так что бы линия тоже ресайзилась, тогда картинки будут сжиматься вместе с линией.

**2. С помощью формулы.**

По сути ваши HTML файл про саму линию ничего не знает, для него это просто картинка. Так что он и не может отслеживать её и прикреплять к ней. Поэтому можно линию задать математичеcкой формулой - sin например. И на основе этой формулы расcчитывать позиционирование элементов. Тогда и выводить линию надо будет не картинкой а например через `SVG`.

**3. С помощью SVG.**

`SVG` это векторный формат графики.

SVG формат линии хранит также информацию о всех её точках, поэтому можно на основе `PATH` расчитать координаты конкретной точки.

Можно сразу на `SVG` прикрепить элементы (кружочки). Там и анимация на `hover` может быть и другое. И рассчитывать не придётся. В SVG есть много вариантов масштабирования графики.

**4. Делать media query на многие варианты разрешения.**

Долго, но разбираться с технологиями или математикой не придётся. Я бы так делать не стал.

Из всех вариантов наиболее перспективным мне видится 1 вариант, как самый простой, и `SVG` вариант как наиболее универсальный.

Comment: Проблема в том, что линия есть только в png, вместе с полупрозрачным фоном. Я в принципе отрисовал в ручную clip-path для контейнера, но забыл что border не сработает для линии. Видимо придется в svg все отрисовывать руками. Через mq не хочу делать, как-то непрофессионально что ли. Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: На `less` есть возможность создавать селекторы автоматически - рекурсивно, там тоже можно формулу подобрать и тогда вручную не придётся прописывать. `mq` сгенерируются автоматически. Saas я не знаю, но думаю там тоже есть подобная функциональность. Так я бы тоже делать не стал, так как SVG видится оптимальным решением,  пишу сюда как возможный вариант через `mq` автогенерацию.

Comment: Вы про директиву function?
Сделаю через SVG, как и думал изначально)
Спасибо, за дополнение.

Comment: В `less` это `loops` - http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature

Comment: А в `saas` тоже есть `for` - http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Control_Directives___Expressions

Comment: Подумал про for, написал про function.